# How to get the index name after regrouping for certain maximum value of another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing election data of four different years.  Column "Votes" contain the total votes a party got for different constituencies in each year. I need to find the winning party (party who has got maximum total votes) of each year. I have grouped the data using "Election year" and "Party". Now how can I get the Election Year and Party for the above case?

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Election Year', 'Party']).sum()
print(df1.loc[df1['Votes'].idxmax()])
```

The above code is not giving the expected result.

I have attached the
[Dataframe after using groupby](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFGnf.jpg)

How can I get the expected result. Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: It might be worth reading [how to make a good pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). What is your expected result?

Comment: I want to get the "Party" name getting maximum votes for a particular year. So, there should be four Parties as there are 4 different years in the dataframe.